Problema Abertura da Câmera através de um form principal | OPENCV JAVA
Estou com uma classe que tem como objetivo carregar minha webcan e reconhecer o rosto e olhos, esta classe executa sem nenhum problema se eu executar ela direto pelo método main, porem estou criando um formulário simples com um botão que ira chamar essa classe que processa a imagem e mostra em um forme pequeno, mas quando eu chamo essa classe ela abre um form em branco.
Segue o código que processa a imagem da camera:
package Modelo;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.HighGui;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.objdetect.Objdetect;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Main {

static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Inicializar a captura de vídeo da webcam
    VideoCapture captura = new VideoCapture(0);
    if (!captura.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao abrir a webcam");
        return;
    }

    // Carregar o classificador de rostos / Olhos
    CascadeClassifier detectorDeRostos = new CascadeClassifier();
    CascadeClassifier detectorDeOlhos = new CascadeClassifier();
    detectorDeRostos.load("data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    detectorDeOlhos.load("data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml");
    Mat quadro = new Mat();
    Mat cinza = new Mat();

    while (captura.read(quadro)) {
        // Converter a imagem para escala de cinza
        Imgproc.cvtColor(quadro, cinza, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // Detectar rostos
        MatOfRect deteccoesDeRostos = new MatOfRect();
        detectorDeRostos.detectMultiScale(cinza, deteccoesDeRostos, 1.1, 3, Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, new Size(30, 30), new Size());

        // Detectar olhos
        MatOfRect deteccoesDeOlhos = new MatOfRect();
        for (Rect retangulo : deteccoesDeRostos.toArray()) {
            Mat regiaoDoRosto = cinza.submat(retangulo);
            detectorDeOlhos.detectMultiScale(regiaoDoRosto, deteccoesDeOlhos);
            for (Rect olho : deteccoesDeOlhos.toArray()) {
                Point centroDoOlho = new Point(retangulo.x + olho.x + olho.width / 2, retangulo.y + olho.y + olho.height / 2);
                Imgproc.circle(quadro, centroDoOlho, 5, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
            }
        }

        // Desenhar um retângulo ao redor dos rostos detectados
        for (Rect retangulo : deteccoesDeRostos.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(quadro, new Point(retangulo.x, retangulo.y), new Point(retangulo.x + retangulo.width, retangulo.y + retangulo.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        // Mostrar o quadro com os rostos detectados
        HighGui.imshow("Detecção de Rostos", quadro);

        // Sair do loop se a tecla 'q' for pressionada

        if (HighGui.waitKey(30) == 'Q') {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Pressione 'Q' para sair");
    }

    captura.release();
    HighGui.destroyAllWindows();
    // Salvar a imagem com os rostos detectados
    String nomeDoArquivo = "src/main/resources/rostos_detectados_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(nomeDoArquivo, quadro);

    System.out.println("Rostos detectados em " + nomeDoArquivo);
}

}
